# Get permission data from Database

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm having problems to do a simple permission system on my Webapp. My DB has a table called "usuario" that has informations about the users of the system. One of these columns is called "privilegio" that has value '0' for administrators and 1 for regular users. An administrator has the power to Add and edit users on the system. Im trying to take this behavior querying my database with the cod of the logged user and getting its permission. If the user is not on the administrator group (privilegio=1) then the add/edit/delete buttons will be unset.

```
public function usuario() {
if($this->session->userdata('logged')){ 
  $crud = new grocery_CRUD(); 
  $crud->set_subject("Usuário"); 
  $crud->set_theme('datatables'); 
  $crud->set_table("usuario"); 
  (...) 
  $crud->field_type('privilegio','dropdown',array('0'=>'Administrador','1'=>'Usuario'));
  (...) 
  $this->db->select('privilegio');
  $this->db->get('usuario'); 
  $result = $this->db->where('cod_func',$this->session->userdata('cod_func')); 
  if(!$result){ 
     $crud->unset_add(); 
     $crud->unset_edit(); 
     $crud->unset_delete(); 
  }
(...)
```

The problem (and the question) is that this code only list the user that is logged on, not the others already registered on the system and stored on "usuario" table. I wonder that the list is been made by my query (what is not the behavior I would like) I hope you could undestand my doubt. Sorry for my bad english.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're having trouble with the active record functions...

When you use the function

```
$this->db->get('usuario');
```

This translates to the query:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario
```

So try changing your code to something like this:

```
$this->db->select('privilegio');
$this->db->from('usuario');
$this->db->where('cod_func',$this->session->userdata('cod_func')); 
$this->db->limit(1); //You're only expecting one result
$result = $this->db->get(); // Save the result to the variable result
```

//Edited for the comment, something like

```
$result = $result->first_row('array'); //Here I'm fetching only the first row into an array
$privilegio = $result['privilegio']; //Im saving the result from the query in the variable $privilegio
```

This translates to:

```
SELECT priviliegio FROM usuario WHERE cod_func = 'some_value' LIMIT 1;
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the $result variable, please refer to documentation to see what you can do...

[Generating Query Results](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: Thanks for your attention.
I changed the code Like you said, but cant use the variable "$result" Like i would Like. 
I want to get the result of the query and test if its 0 or 1, but i got an error saying that i cant convert "CI_DB to int". 

Thanks again people.

Comment: @Leonardo $result is as the error says a CI_DB Object you need to fetch that result in order to access it, I edited the answer to show you one way to do it, but I strongly suggest to read the link in order to get a better understanding

Comment: Thank you again. Worked like a charm. I really need to read again the guide. Thank You!